# Mono : is there a System.Tuple?

Tags: c#, f#, mono, c#-to-f#

I am trying to do some interop between C# and F# in Mono. Is there a System.Tuple in Mono C#? I can see the one in Mono.CSharp, but that doesn't seem to be the same type as F# (a' * b'). So,

(a) Is there a System.Tuple in Mono C#
or (b) Is there a cast between tuples in Mono C# and F#?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes Mono supports a `Tuple` type.  I know it's in 4.0 but I've seen comments of it's availability since version 2.6.

- [Tuple Documentation](http://www.go-mono.com/docs/index.aspx?link=T%3aSystem.Tuple)

Comment: Thanks for your help - problem was actually the fact that I didn't realise that MonoDevelop defaults to .Net 3.5 for C# projects. As soon as I upgraded to 4.0, all became clear.

Answer (score 2):

It also depends on what version of F# compiler do you use. If you compile your F# code using F# compiler for .NET 2.0, then it will use `FSharp.Core.dll` for .NET 2.0, which contains the declaration of `Tuple<..>` classes. Then you can simply reference `FSharp.Core.dll` from your C# project and you'll find tuple there (It is in the `System` namespace to make it compatible with .NET 4)

I believe that the ZIP release from Microsoft and the [F# packages](http://fsxplat.codeplex.com/) both contain 2.0 version. I'm not sure about the version of F# bundled with Mono 2.10 though or the one in Debian.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried

```
System.Tuple<int, int> t2 = new System.Tuple<int, int>(1, 2);
```

and it worked, on version `4.0`