# Compiling System.Tuple in Mono

Tags: c#, mono

I'm attempting to compile some C# with gmcs version 2.11.0 that includes System.Tuple. Supposedly it does exist in Mono (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5346453/mono-is-there-a-system-tuple) and it is possible to compile using the flag:

```
gmcs -langversion:future
```

It doesn't seem to matter which langversion I use, the compiler always gives the same error:

```
error CS0234: The type or namespace name `Tuple' does not exist in the namespace `System'. Are you missing an assembly reference?
```

How can I compile C# code using Mono that uses System.Tuple?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the problem is that `gmcs` targets the Mono framework version equivalent to .NET 3.5. You could *either* try to persuade gmcs to target the Mono framework version equivalent to .NET 4, or you could use `dmcs` instead. (I couldn't get it to work even with `gmcs -sdk:4` which I expected to work, so `dmcs` may be a better bet.)

Comment: the new 'mcs' compiler can be used to target different versions of the framework. Otherwise **g**mcs (for generics, 2.0), **s**mcs (for silverlight, 2.0.5), **d**mcs (dynamic, 4.0) will target specific framework versions.