# Compile code using Tuple using Mono's mcs

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, mono, compiler-errors

I have some C# code using `Tuple`s:

```
public class Test {
    static void Main() {
        Tuple<int, int> t = Tuple.Create(0, 1);
    }
}
```

I tried compiling using

```
mcs -debug+ -o Test.exe Test.cs
```

but it gives the error

```
Test.cs(3,9): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Tuple' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?
Compilation failed: 1 error(s), 0 warnings
```

I thought it might be trying to compile against an old version of mscorlib which lacks tuples. Looking at the man page, it seems you specify the version using `-sdk:4`, but that doesn't work either:

```
$ mcs -sdk:4 Test.cs

Unhandled Exception: System.TypeLoadException: Type 'System.Dynamic.BinaryOperationBinder' not found in assembly 'System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'
```

(followed by a stack trace).

I am running:

```
$ mcs --version
Mono C# compiler version 2.10.8.1
```

on Ubuntu Precise. According to the documentation, Mono has supported .NET 4.0 since version 2.8, and in particular [supports `System.Tuple`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5346453/mono-is-there-a-system-tuple), so that shouldn't be the issue.

How do you compile code that uses `Tuple`s?

Comment: @mikez: `dmcs` gives exactly the same error as the first `mcs` error.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Compiling System.Tuple in Mono](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8014244/compiling-system-tuple-in-mono)

Comment: @JimMischel: That question is about the old `gmcs`/`dmcs` compilers.

Comment: @Mechanicalsnail also add `using System;` to Test.cs

Comment: @mikez: Interesting. Adding `using System;` fixes it with `dmcs`, but not with `mcs` or `mcs -sdk:4`.

Comment: @Mechanicalsnail that's what I meant by the *also*! as indicated by the docs, with that version of mono you have still must use `dmcs` to target the 4.0 runtime. the sdk flag just indicates the mscorlib library to build against. see http://www.mono-project.com/CSharp_Compiler

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would *expect* it to fail with `mcs` but work with `dmcs`. I've just installed Mono 2.10.9 on Windows, clean, and here were my results with your code (including `using System;` at the top):

```
c:\Users\Jon\Test>mcs Test.cs
    Test.cs(4,9): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Tuple' could not be
    found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?
    Compilation failed: 1 error(s), 0 warnings

c:\Users\Jon\Test>dmcs Test.cs
    Test.cs(4,25): warning CS0219: The variable `t' is assigned but its value is
    never used
    Compilation succeeded - 1 warning(s)
```

The difference is that `dmcs` uses framework v4 by default whereas `mcs` uses v2. You can get it to work with `mcs` just by specifying the v4 framework:

```
mcs -sdk:4 Test.cs
```

Try that, and also double check that you really had the *same* problem when you used `dmcs`. I wouldn't be surprised if you'd seen that it wasn't a clean compile but didn't notice that it was a different message.

Comment: It turns out that `dmcs` *does* work if `import System;` is included, but `mcs -sdk:4 Test.cs` still throws an exception. Is this a bug in the Linux version? (I have checked that it is a clean compile (no `*.exe` file) in both cases.)

Comment: @Mechanicalsnail: Throwing an exception occurs at execution time - you're still talking about a *compile-time* error, right? It's possible that that was a bug in the version that you're using... personally I'd just use `dmcs`. As of Mono 2.11, you only need `mcs` though. (See http://www.mono-project.com/CSharp_Compiler)

Comment: @JonSkeet it looks like the mono compiler `mcs` is throwing. It is trying to load `System.Dynamic.BinaryOperationBinder` in the wrong version of `System.Core`.

Comment: @mikez: Ah, I hadn't seen the edit showing an exception. That makes more sense. Looks like a bug in that particular version of Mono.